# Swapping two nodes (not values of nodes) in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, swap

I was trying to write a function to swap nodes by value in a linked list. It actually works when nodes are not consecutive. But I get an infinite loop when I attempt to swap consecutive nodes. How can I solve this exceptional problem in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* self-referential structure */
struct listNode {
    char data; /* each listNode contains a character */
    struct listNode *nextPtr; /* pointer to next node*/
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode; /* synonym for struct listNode */
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; /* synonym for ListNode* */


void swap( ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value1, char value2 )
{
    ListNodePtr previousPtr1; /* pointer to previous node whose data is value1 */
    ListNodePtr currentPtr1; /* pointer to node whose data is value1 */
    ListNodePtr previousPtr2; /* pointer to previous node whose data is value2 */
    ListNodePtr currentPtr2; /* pointer to node whose data is value2 */

    previousPtr1 = NULL;
    previousPtr2 = NULL;
    currentPtr1 = *sPtr;
    currentPtr2 = *sPtr;

    /* attempt to find the node that contains value1  */
    while( currentPtr1 != NULL && currentPtr1->data != value1 ) {
        previousPtr1 = currentPtr1;
        currentPtr1 = currentPtr1->nextPtr;
    }

    /* attempt to find the node that contains value2 */
    while( currentPtr2 != NULL && currentPtr2->data != value2 ) {
        previousPtr2 = currentPtr2;
        currentPtr2 = currentPtr2->nextPtr;
    }

    if( currentPtr1 != NULL && currentPtr2 != NULL ) { /* both of the values are found */
        if( previousPtr1 == NULL ) {
            ListNodePtr tmpPtr = currentPtr1->nextPtr;
            *sPtr = currentPtr2;
            previousPtr2->nextPtr = currentPtr1;
            currentPtr1->nextPtr = currentPtr2->nextPtr;
            currentPtr2->nextPtr = tmpPtr;
        }
        else if ( previousPtr2 == NULL ) {
            ListNodePtr tmpPtr = currentPtr2->nextPtr;
            *sPtr = currentPtr1;
            previousPtr1->nextPtr = currentPtr2;
            currentPtr2->nextPtr = currentPtr1->nextPtr;
            currentPtr1->nextPtr = tmpPtr;

        }
        else {
            ListNodePtr tmpPtr = currentPtr2->nextPtr;
            previousPtr1->nextPtr = currentPtr2;
            currentPtr2->nextPtr = currentPtr1->nextPtr;
            previousPtr2->nextPtr = currentPtr1;
            currentPtr1->nextPtr = tmpPtr;
        }
    }
    else { /* at least one of the values is not found */
        printf("Not found!\n");
    }
}
int main( void )
{
    ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL; /* initially there are no nodes */
}
```

Obviously it's not all of the main function, there are little piece of codes that take input for this function and for lots of other functions such as like reverse in this code, but I don't have problem with them.

EDIT: I don't want to swap the values inside of the nodes. I want to swap actual nodes.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are swapping nodes instead of swapping the contents of the nodes?

Comment: I see another problem: When `previousPtr1 == NULL` following the loops, is there any guarantee that `previousPtr2 != NULL`? If not, then why are you dereferencing `previousPtr2`? This code seems unnecessarily complex...

Comment: your finding the two elements, then just  change the value of two nodes    `temp_val=cur_ptr1->data ; cur_ptr1->data=cur_ptr2->data ; cur_ptr2->data = temp_val;`

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour yes, there is. because both of them cannot be the first element. And yes, I know it's a little bit complex but I had to handle the situation where one of the elements is the first node, because head must be changed in this situation.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. I haven't picked though the code, but remember, swapping nodes in a linked-list is just a **pointer rewiring** issue. The data values in memory don't change, only the node `next/prev` pointers point to change. It can be a challenge, but simply creating a `tmp` node that preserves the `prev/next` pointer values of one node while you rewire the next will do -- **except** if you are swapping the **first** node. In that case the new first node value must be changed to hold the list address.

Comment: FYI - Instead of editing your question to include the solution, you should add the solution as an answer to your question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin swapping the first node was the first problem that I've reallized. Soon I've realized that there are problems swapping consecutive nodes so the code get a bit more complex then I expected.

Comment: Just for clarification, your list is non-circular, correct? From your swap routine, it appears that way, but it is worth making sure you are not setting `lastNode->nextPtr = firstNode` anywhere in your code are you? Just a plain old `lastNode->nextPtr = NULL` linked-list, right?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes it's non-circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be compounded by the declaration of unnecessary variables and the use of unnecessary values causing your code to become unnecessarily complex. If you consider that you're starting with the `ListNodePtr *sPtr`, and both of your loops are changing based on `ListNodePtr *` values, then you might realise that this algorithm can be better expressed using two variables initialised to `sPtr`, rather than four, two of which are initialised to `NULL` and the other two `*sPtr`.

```
ListNodePtr *x = sPtr,
            *y = sPtr;

while (*x != NULL && (*x)->data != value1) {
    x = &(*x)->nextPtr;
}

while (*y != NULL && (*y)->data != value2) {
    y = &(*y)->nextPtr;
}
```

The benefit is two-fold:

- Because of the initialisation to `sPtr` rather than `NULL`, you won't need to check if any of the variables are `NULL` later on (which seems to be contributing to the fogginess of deciding which values you need to swap).
- It should be much clearer which values you need to swap, now, but in case it isn't: Swap `*x` and `*y`, swap `(*x)->nextPtr` and `(*y)->nextPtr`.

Comment: Well, I get segmentation fault from your code. Are you sure that everything is allrigtht ?

Comment: It does not hold previous pointer. So how does it make them point to current pointers?

Comment: How can you get a segfault from this code when you haven't even given us the main? That's not fair! Regardless, there was an error in my code which I've fixed now. You can see it running without a segfault, and passing `assert` tests to show that I've swapped the positions of `b` and `c` at http://ideone.com/Flbwy7

Answer (score 0):

After finding the positions of the node to be swapped just write a simple swap routine like this-

```
void swap(struct listNode *a,struct listNode *b)
{
  char t=a->data;
  a->data=b->data;
  b->data=t;
}
```

If you are swapping nodes by value then get the benefit out of it. Just swap the values.

Now in case you want to swap nodes-(not by value)

```
//p-first node to be swapped
//p1-prev node of p
//r-second node to be swapped
//r1-prev node of r
// a temporay listNode *
temp=r->link;
r->link=p->link;
p->link=temp;
if(p1!=NULL)
   p1->link=r;
else
   startpointer=r;
r1->link=p;
}
```

Comment: The OP is trying to swap the nodes, not the contents of the nodes. Whether that is a means to the end is not clear.

Comment: @R Sahu.: The question is to swap nodes by values. In that this is what one should do? Otherwise he has asked the question in a wrong way I think.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between "swap nodes by value" and "swap values of nodes". It's not clear to me what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You Already find the two values corresponding address, in the linked list.

```
  if ( cur_ptr1!=NULL && cur_ptr2!=NULL){
        int  temp_val=cur_ptr1->data ; 
         cur_ptr1->data=cur_ptr2->data ;
         cur_ptr2->data = temp_val
   }
```

Now the two values in the linked list are swapped.

Consider you have a nodes like

```
 |1|->|2|->|3|->|4|->|5|->|6|->NULL
```

Now your going to swap the node 2 and 5. then we can just change the values like this

```
 |1|->|5|->|3|->|4|->|2|->|6|->NULL
```

Comment: But it only swaps the values in the nodes. It does not swap the nodes.

Comment: @FatihErdemKızılkaya when we are swapping the nodes , then the same thing will happen

Comment: Yes, I know but there are more complex situations where we 're supposed to swap a bunch of data.  This just a problem set by the way.

Comment: @FatihErdemKızılkaya - Each time  two values only going to swap. so what is the problem we get..

Answer (score 0):

you should also consider using a premetive iterator instead of while loop.
ill give you an example:

```
/**
* Macro for iterating over a list.
*
* Declares a new variable to hold each element of the list.
* Use this macro for iterating through the list conveniently.
* Note that this mcaro modifies the internal iterator.
* For example, the following code will go through a list of strings and print
* them to the standard output:
* @code
* void printList(List listOfStrings) {
*   LIST_FOREACH(char*, str, listOfStrings) {
*     printf("%s\\n", str);
*   }
* }
* @endcode

* @param type The type of the elements in the list
* @param iterator The name of the variable to hold the next list element
* @param list the list to iterate over
*/
#define LIST_FOREACH(type,iterator,list) \
for(type iterator = listGetFirst(list) ; \
    iterator ;\
    iterator = listGetNext(list))
```

listGetNext and listGetFirst are standart list getters functions.
it is a very premetive iterator, but for this kind of "heavy duty" works, i think it is a sufficent technique.